# Is this javascript promise right?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am learning AngularJS and trying to implement Angular UI Bootstrap Typeahead in a simple search app using Elasticsearch. I want to use the $http service to load asynchronous results and have not worked much with js promises.

**UPDATE**: I've done some more learning and testing

I've include the Typeahead as a dependency in my app:

```
var searchApp = angular.module('searchApp', ['elasticsearch', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Here is the js promise code with the ES Match query mapped to the content.autocomplete field:

```
this.getSuggestions = function(query) {
var deferred = $q.defer();

esClient.search({
  index: 'bigtestindex',
  body: {
    "query": {
      "match": {
          "content.autocomplete": {
            "query": query,
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      },
    "suggest": {
      "text": query,
      "phraseSuggestion": {
        "phrase": {
          "field": "content",
          "direct_generator": [{
            "field": "content",
            "suggest_mode": "popular",
            "min_word_length": 3,
            "prefix_length": 2
          }]
        }
      }
    },
    "size": 5,
    "_source": ["content.autocomplete"]
  }
}).then(function(es_return) {
  deferred.resolve(es_return);
}, function(error) {
  deferred.reject(error);
});

return deferred.promise;
```

};

With this code, I am trying to achieve the asynchronous results as shown [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

Here is the relevant html to display possible matches:

```
<li ng-repeat="gram in autocomplete.edgengrams">
        <p ng-mousedown="searchForSuggestion()"><small>Search Suggestions: &mdash;</small>{{gram.content}}</p>
  </li>
```

Comment: Hey user3125823, I'd love to help but I'm unsure what you're asking. You should try to unpack this general 'does this seem right question' into something that's more concrete and narrow.

Comment: We are keen to know what you are trying to achieve and what is not working as expected ?

Comment: You can directly return the $http.get promise.

Comment: That doesn't look right, it looks like the [defered antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

Comment: @DaneO'Connor tying to achieve the asynchronous results as shown https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: `var deferred = $q.defer();` is still redundant.

Comment: thanks guys, have learned alot, got it working, now just refinement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$http.get() return a promise object already , there is no need to wrap the result in another promise object..

For your reference
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get